# How do I tar a directory without retaining the directory structure?

Tags: linux, unix, gnu, tar

I'm working on a backup script and want to tar up a file directory:

```
tar czf ~/backup.tgz /home/username/drupal/sites/default/files
```

This tars it up, but when I untar the resulting file, it includes the full file structure: the files are in `home/username/drupal/sites/default/files`.

Is there a way to exclude the parent directories, so that the resulting tar just knows about the last directory (`files`)?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
cd /home/username/drupal/sites/default/files
tar czf ~/backup.tgz *
```

Comment: You can also use the -C option of tar.

Comment: cd is not recommended and error prone, e.g. big scripts or makefiles. The answer below is more generally usable and correct.

Comment: Tries `-C` and `--directory` didn't work for me on Ubuntu 16.04. This is only option that works.

Comment: This is the only option that works -C add a . root folder, which is not what we want.

Answer (score 197):

Use the --directory option:

```
 tar czf ~/backup.tgz --directory=/home/username/drupal/sites/default files
```

Comment: What if I want to put 2 directories here?

Comment: @user3352668 simply add two directories. E.g. if default contains "files" and "morefiles", simply add "morefiles" to the string of nbt. Btw: Best solution is nbt's, should be the accepted answer

Comment: **-C DIR** is same as **--directory=DIR**, changes directory to DIR

Comment: Just thought I'd mention that the order here is significant. You can't have the `--directory="/home/username/drupal/sites/default files"` infront of the destination `~/backup.tgz`.

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski Note that the path given by the `--directory` option is not `"/home/username/drupal/sites/default files"`. It is `/home/username/drupal/sites/default`, followed by a positional argument specifying the name of the directory to be tar'ed, `files`.

Comment: I'm not able to use wildcards in files. How to use wildcards using directory?

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski That's because `~/backup.tgz` is the option argument for the `-f` option. I imagine that it's fine to do `tar czC /home/username/drupal/sites/default -f ~/backup.tgz files`

Comment: @PrashantPokhriyal `cd /home/username/drupal/sites/default; tar czf ~/backup.tgz files/*; cd -`

Answer (score 71):

Hi I've a better solution when enter in the specified directory it's impossible (Makefiles,etc)

```
tar -cjvf files.tar.bz2 -C directory/contents/to/be/compressed .
```

**Do not forget the dot (.) at the end !!**

Comment: **-C DIR** is same as **--directory=DIR**, changes directory to DIR

Comment: What does the dot at the end do?

Comment: @BruceSun The **-C** changes your working directory. The dot tells tar which directory you want to archive (i.e the current working directory).

Comment: If you omit the dot at the end, you likely will receive the warning: [tar: Cowardly refusing to create an empty archive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44380154/tar-cowardly-refusing-to-create-an-empty-archive)

Comment: Everyone talks about the -C option or --directory but without the little '.' at the end as @MaikolD mentioned it, it does not work - at least on my environment.

Comment: This still leaves you with a `.` folder in the root of the tar

Comment: This is the only recipe that actually worked. Thanks!

Comment: This does not correctly tar only the contents of the directory "directory/contents/to/be/compressed". The dot is causing a directory "." to be created and that directory contains the contents. 
Does anyone have a way to only tar the contents of the source directory?

Answer (score 7):

## Create a tar archive

```sh
tar czf  $sourcedir/$backup_dir.tar --directory=$sourcedir WEB-INF en
```

## Un-tar files on a local machine

```sh
tar -xvf $deploydir/med365/$backup_dir.tar -C $deploydir/med365/
```

## Upload to a server

```sh
scp -r -i $privatekey $sourcedir/$backup_dir.tar $server:$deploydir/med365/
echo "File uploaded.. deployment folders"
```

## Un-tar on server

```sh
ssh -i $privatekey $server tar -xvf $deploydir/med365/$backup_dir.tar -C $deploydir/med365/
```

Answer (score 7):

To build on [nbt's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5696001) and [MaikoID's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16820591) solutions:

```sh
tar -czf destination.tar.gz -C source/directory $(ls source/directory)
```

This solution:

- Includes all files and folders in the directory
- Does not include any of the directory structure (or `.`) in the final product
- Does not require you to change directories.

However, it requires the directory to be given twice, so it may be most useful in another script. It may also be less efficient if there are a lot of files/folders in `source/directory`. Adjust the subcommand as necessary.

So for instance for the following structure:

```
|- source
|  |- one
|  `- two
`- working
```

the following command:

```sh
working$ tar -czf destination.tar.gz -C ../source $(ls ../source)
```

will produce `destination.tar.gz` where both `one` and `two` (and sub-files/-folders) are the first items.

Answer (score 2):

To gunzip all txt (*.txt)  files from `/home/myuser/workspace/zip_from/` 
to `/home/myuser/workspace/zip_to/` without directory structure of source files use following command:

```
tar -P -cvzf /home/myuser/workspace/zip_to/mydoc.tar.gz  --directory="/home/myuser/workspace/zip_from/" *.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to tar files while keeping the structure but ignore it partially or completely when extracting, use the *--strip-components* argument when extracting.

In this case, where the full path is */home/username/drupal/sites/default/files*, the following command would extract the tar.gz content without the full parent directory structure, keeping only the last directory of the path (e.g. *files/file1*).

`tar -xzv --strip-components=5 -f backup.tgz`

I've found this tip on https://www.baeldung.com/linux/tar-archive-without-directory-structure#5-using-the---strip-components-option.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
gzip -dc "<your_file>.tgz" | tar x -C <location>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me -C or --directory did not work, I use this

```sh
cd source/directory/or/file
tar -cvzf destination/packaged-app.tgz *.jar
# this will put your current directory to what it previously was
cd -
```

Answer (score -1):

Kindly use the below command to generate tar file without directory structure

```
tar -C <directoryPath> -cvzf <Path of the tar.gz file> filename1 filename2... filename N
```

eg:

```
tar -C /home/project/files -cvzf /home/project/files/test.tar.gz text1.txt text2.txt
```

Answer (score -3):

```
tar -Cczf ~/backup.tgz /home/username/drupal/sites/default/files
```

-C does the cd for you

Comment: This will not work. See MaikoID's and Neil Butterworth's solutions.

Comment: `-C` works, but has to be used like `-C <dir> file1 file2 ...`