# tar: Cowardly refusing to create an empty archive

Tags: linux, fedora, tar

I use the following tar command to try to backup my entire file system

```
tar -cvpzf test/backup.tar.gz --exclude=/test
```

And I receive the following error message

```
tar: Cowardly refusing to create an empty archive
Try 'tar --help' or 'tar --usage' for more information.
```

Can somebody point me in the right direction as to how to use tar and explain why it's trying to create an empty archive?

Comment: You have not given what files/paths you want to tar up.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: Okay, I did tar -cvpzf / test/backup.tar.gz --exclude=/test but now I'm coming up with this error

tar (child): /: Cannot open: Is a directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

Comment: @NicoleLouise After `-cvpzf` the very next argument has to be the name of the tar file you want to create. Then after that you can specify the files and/or directories to be included. So, `tar -cvpzf test/backup.tar.gz --exclude=/test /` should work. However, you may want to consider avoiding the absolute pathname: see https://www.inforbiro.com/blog/absolute-paths-with-tar-command

Answer (score 4):

You defined what to exclude, but didn't define what you actually want in the archive. Supply at least one path. If you want entire filesystem, then `tar -c....... /`